# How to Change the Font in Matlab's "exportgraphics" Function in a PDF Vector Graphic

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, vector-graphics

I am trying to export a Matlab figure as a PDF vector graphic using Matlab's "exportgraphics" function as suggested in the Matlab Documentation. For reference see:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exportgraphics.html

Everything works fine. However the font used for the title, x- and y- label, and the ticks does not match the one used in the Matlab figure that pops up after running the code. It changes to the font "times" that does not fit my purpose. Now I would like to specify the font for all three: the title, the x- and y- labels, and the ticks (numbers). To do this separately is not necessary, but optional.
Does anybody have a suggestion?

As you can see in my code I already tried to influence the font by specifying it in (e.g.) the "ylabel" command.

```
figure
plot(Zeit1,Temperatur1,'LineWidth',2)
grid on
title('Temperatur-Messprogramm für Messreihe 1')
xlabel('Zeit [min]')
ylabel('Temperatur [°C]', 'FontName', 'Helvetica')
xlim([-5 150])
ylim([-5 405])
set(gca,'FontSize',30)
exportgraphics(gcf,'Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_1.jpg','Resolution',600)
exportgraphics(gcf,'Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_1.pdf','Resolution',600,'ContentType','vector')
```

**This does influence the font displayed in the Matlab figure, however changes nothing for the programmatically exported PDF vector graphic. This one stays in the font "Times", no matter what ever I do.** Trying to change the default font (`set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName','scrbook')`) for all figures as suggested by another user does also not lead to the desired effect.

The graphic created by

```
exportgraphics(gcf,'Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_1.jpg','Resolution',600)
```

is in the correct font, but a regular image. The graphic created by

```
exportgraphics(gcf,'Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_1.pdf','Resolution',600,'ContentType','vector')
```

is in the wrong font, but in the desired PDF vector graphic format.

Thank you for your support!

with kind regards,
Timon

- This post has been edited after finding out that "times" is the default font for the PDF vector graphic and is therefore an ill test method to see if one can change the font.

Comment: `exportgraphics` is new in the latest MATLAB release. This might be a bug, consider reporting it to the MathWorks. The most popular tool to export figures as PDF is [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig). I recommend you give that a try.

Comment: The documentation claims that “The PDF includes embeddable fonts when the ContentType is set to 'vector'.” If it uses a PS font (Times) this might not be the case. Also, is “scrbook” an actual font on your system?

Comment: @CrisLuengo you are absolutely correct: "scrbook" is not a font. I got confused there. I will therefore edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after contemplating a while, I ditched the idea of using the exportgraphics function. Possibly it does have a bug since it was first introduced in Matlab 2020a. I went on to use a function called matlab2tikz, which one can download here:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz

This function makes it possible to save the figure as a vector graphic and include it into LaTeX using the \input command (see code at the end of this post). The font in use will be the one used as default in LaTeX (computer modern roman), which is what I ultimately wanted to achieve with all of this. For details see:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dg7z3bs-eA8

(one does not need to understand German to understand the video)

The final Matlab code I use is:

```
gomatlab2tikz = true

figure('units','centimeters','position',[0 0 15.5 10.333])
plot(Zeit3,Temperatur3,'LineWidth',2)
grid on
title('Temperatur-Messprogramm für Messreihe 3')
xlabel('Zeit [min]') %Zeit [min]
ylabel('Temperatur [°C]') %Temperatur [°C]
xlim([0 150])
ylim([0 400])
xticks(linspace(0,150,16))
yticks(linspace(0,400,21))
set(gca,'FontSize',11)
if gosave == true
    exportgraphics(gcf,'Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_3.jpg','Resolution',150)
    exportgraphics(gcf,'Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_3.pdf','Resolution',150,'ContentType','vector')
end
if gomatlab2tikz == true
    matlab2tikz('Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_3.tikz')
end
```

At least in my case the figure shown by Matlab does not have to correct size in centimetres. However the dimensions of the figure will be correct if one imports the .tikz file via the \input command into LaTeX. For further improved lay-outing one can use the \resizebox command.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
         \resizebox{1.00\linewidth}{!}{\input{Figures/Versuche/Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_1.tikz}}
\caption{Temperatur Messprogramm Messreihe 1}
\label{Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_1}
\end{figure}
```